# I'm new to asp.net mvc and entity Jquery ajax error says 'The entity or complex type 'myModel'' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.'

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Here's my code on the controller any help would be helpful guys 
thank you very much!

```
public JsonResult GetJobList()
        {
            jQueryAjaxEntities db = new jQueryAjaxEntities();
            List<jobdetail> job = db.jobdetails.Select(x => new jobdetail
            {
                JobID = x.JobID,
                Task_Name = x.Task_Name,
                Description = x.Description,
                Date_Started = x.Date_Started,
                Date_Finished = x.Date_Finished,
                Status = x.Status,
            }).ToList();

            return Json(job, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: Where is the 'myModel' type located at?

Comment: @jeff its the jobdetail i just changed it in the question because the question needs to be shortened

Comment: add it because that is where your problem lies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the issue is using the mapped entity itself. Try using a DTO (create new dto class)

```
public class JobDetailsDTO
{
     public int JobID { get; set; }
    // Other fields you may need
}
```

And then:

```
using(var db = new jQueryAjaxEntities())
{
    var job = db.jobdetails.Select(x => new JobDetailsDTO
        {
            JobID = x.JobID,
            Task_Name = x.Task_Name,
            Description = x.Description,
            Date_Started = x.Date_Started,
            Date_Finished = x.Date_Finished,
            Status = x.Status,
        }).ToList();

        return Json(job, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: i'm having an error that says cannot implicity convert type after i did what you said sir

Comment: all goods sir i just forgot to change the jobdetail to jobdetailsDTO thank you very much!!